# Make homestead global in Windows OS

Tags: php, git, path, composer-php

I installed composer and added C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin; to my PATH through config in windows. So I can access composer with git globally.

Next I installed homestead: composer global require "laravel/homestead=~2.0"

The map was automaticaly created in C:\Users\Bart\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\laravel\homestead

I added this path to my PATH environment variable in windows so I could access homestead globally. But this doesn't work like it did with composer.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The binary file (the executable on windows) is put in `C:\Users\Bart\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin` (this contains all executables for all globally installed packages).

You have to add this directory to your PATH file.

Comment: thx indeed. Just found it out myself. I thought I needed the other path cause when using git in that map I could access homestead.